# How to add start button and password protection for quizzes on the web?

Tags: html, password-protection

I found the following code at [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/boopalan002/pen/yKZVGa)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  
  var questions = [{
    question: "1. How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
    choices: ["('Hello World')", "msgBox('Hello World');", "alertBox('Hello World');", "alert('Hello World');"],
    correctAnswer: 3
}, {
    question: "2. How to empty an array in JavaScript?",
    choices: ["arrayList[]", "arrayList(0)", "arrayList.length=0", "arrayList.len(0)"],
    correctAnswer: 2
}, {
    question: "3. What function to add an element at the begining of an array and one at the end?",
    choices: ["push,unshift", "unshift,push", "first,push", "unshift,last"],
    correctAnswer: 1
}, {
    question: "4. What will this output? var a = [1, 2, 3]; console.log(a[6]);",
    choices: ["undefined", "0", "prints nothing", "Syntax error"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}, {
    question: "5. What would following code return? console.log(typeof typeof 1);",
    choices: ["string", "number", "Syntax error", "undefined"],
    correctAnswer: 0
},{
    question: "6. Which software company developed JavaScript?",
    choices: ["Mozilla", "Netscape", "Sun Microsystems", "Oracle"],
    correctAnswer: 1
},{
    question: "7. What would be the result of 3+2+'7'?",
    choices: ["327", "12", "14", "57"],
    correctAnswer: 3
},{
    question: "8. Look at the following selector: $('div'). What does it select?",
    choices: ["The first div element", "The last div element", "All div elements", "Current div element"],
    correctAnswer: 2
},{
    question: "9. How can a value be appended to an array?",
    choices: ["arr(length).value;", "arr[arr.length]=value;", "arr[]=add(value);", "None of these"],
    correctAnswer: 1
},{
    question: "10. What will the code below output to the console? console.log(1 +  +'2' + '2');",
    choices: ["'32'", "'122'", "'13'", "'14'"],
    correctAnswer: 0
}];


var currentQuestion = 0;
var viewingAns = 0;
var correctAnswers = 0;
var quizOver = false;
var iSelectedAnswer = [];
    var c=10;
    var t;
  
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // Display the first question
    displayCurrentQuestion();
  
    $(this).find(".quizMessage").hide();
    $(this).find(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    timedCount();
    
    $(this).find(".preButton").on("click", function () 
    {       
        
        if (!quizOver) 
        {
            if(currentQuestion == 0) { return false; }
    
            if(currentQuestion == 1) {
              $(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            
                currentQuestion--; // Since we have already displayed the first question on DOM ready
                if (currentQuestion < questions.length) 
                {
                    displayCurrentQuestion();
                    
                }                   
        } else {
            if(viewingAns == 3) { return false; }
            currentQuestion = 0; viewingAns = 3;
            viewResults();      
        }
    });

    
    // On clicking next, display the next question
    $(this).find(".nextButton").on("click", function () 
    {
        if (!quizOver) 
        {
            
            var val = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

            if (val == undefined) 
            {
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").text("Please select an answer");
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").show();
            } 
            else 
            {
                // TODO: Remove any message -> not sure if this is efficient to call this each time....
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").hide();
                if (val == questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer) 
                {
                    correctAnswers++;
                }
                iSelectedAnswer[currentQuestion] = val;
                
                currentQuestion++; // Since we have already displayed the first question on DOM ready
                if(currentQuestion >= 1) {
                      $('.preButton').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                if (currentQuestion < questions.length) 
                {
                    displayCurrentQuestion();
                    
                } 
                else 
                {
                    displayScore();
                    $('#iTimeShow').html('Time is Over!!!!');
                    $('#timer').html("You scored: " + correctAnswers + " out of: " + questions.length);
                    c=185;
                    $(document).find(".preButton").text("View Answer");
                    $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Play Again?");
                    quizOver = true;
                    return false;
                    
                }
            }
                    
        }   
        else 
        { // quiz is over and clicked the next button (which now displays 'Play Again?'
            quizOver = false; $('#iTimeShow').html('Time Remaining:'); iSelectedAnswer = [];
            $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Next Question");
            $(document).find(".preButton").text("Previous Question");
             $(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            resetQuiz();
            viewingAns = 1;
            displayCurrentQuestion();
            hideScore();
        }
    });
});



function timedCount()
    {
        if(c == 15) 
        { 
            return false; 
        }
        
        var hours = parseInt( c / 3600 ) % 24;
        var minutes = parseInt( c / 60 ) % 60;
        var seconds = c % 60;
        var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);            
        $('#timer').html(result);
        
        if(c == 0 )
        {
                    displayScore();
                    $('#iTimeShow').html('Time is Over!!!');
                    $('#timer').html("You scored: " + correctAnswers + " out of: " + questions.length);
                    c=185;
                    $(document).find(".preButton").text("View Answer");
                    $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Play Again?");
                    quizOver = true;
                    return false;
                    
        }
        
        if(c == 0 )
        {   
            if (!quizOver) 
            {
                var val = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
                if (val == questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer) 
                {
                    correctAnswers++;
                }
                currentQuestion++; // Since we have already displayed the first question on DOM ready
                
                if (currentQuestion < questions.length) 
                {
                    displayCurrentQuestion();
                    c=15;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    displayScore();
                    $('#timer').html('');
                    c=16;
                    $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Play Again?");
                    quizOver = true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else 
            { // quiz is over and clicked the next button (which now displays 'Play Again?'
                quizOver = false;
                $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Next Question");
                resetQuiz();
                displayCurrentQuestion();
                hideScore();
            }       
        }   
        c = c - 1;
        t = setTimeout(function()
        {
            timedCount()
        },1000);
    }
    
    
// This displays the current question AND the choices
function displayCurrentQuestion() 
{

    if(c == 15) { c = 10; timedCount(); }
    //console.log("In display current Question");
    var question = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    var questionClass = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .question");
    var choiceList = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .choiceList");
    var numChoices = questions[currentQuestion].choices.length;
    // Set the questionClass text to the current question
    $(questionClass).text(question);
    // Remove all current <li> elements (if any)
    $(choiceList).find("li").remove();
    var choice;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) 
    {
        choice = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i];
        
        if(iSelectedAnswer[currentQuestion] == i) {
            $('<li><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" checked="checked"  value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
        } else {
            $('<li><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
        }
    }
}

function resetQuiz()
{
    currentQuestion = 0;
    correctAnswers = 0;
    hideScore();
}

function displayScore()
{
    $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").text("You scored: " + correctAnswers + " out of: " + questions.length);
    $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").show();
}

function hideScore() 
{
    $(document).find(".result").hide();
}

// This displays the current question AND the choices
function viewResults() 
{

    if(currentQuestion == 10) { currentQuestion = 0;return false; }
    if(viewingAns == 1) { return false; }

    hideScore();
    var question = questions[currentQuestion].question;
    var questionClass = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .question");
    var choiceList = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .choiceList");
    var numChoices = questions[currentQuestion].choices.length;
    // Set the questionClass text to the current question
    $(questionClass).text(question);
    // Remove all current <li> elements (if any)
    $(choiceList).find("li").remove();
    var choice;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) 
    {
        choice = questions[currentQuestion].choices[i];
        
        if(iSelectedAnswer[currentQuestion] == i) {
            if(questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer == i) {
                $('<li style="border:2px solid green;margin-top:10px;"><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" checked="checked"  value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
            } else {
                $('<li style="border:2px solid red;margin-top:10px;"><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" checked="checked"  value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
            }
        } else {
            if(questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer == i) {
                $('<li style="border:2px solid green;margin-top:10px;"><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
            } else {
                $('<li><input type="radio" class="radio-inline" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio" />' +  ' ' + choice  + '</li>').appendTo(choiceList);
            }
        }
    }
    
    currentQuestion++;
    
    setTimeout(function()
        {
            viewResults();
        },3000);
}

</script>
                               
<div class="quizContainer container-fluid well well-lg">
        <div id="quiz1" class="text-center">
            <h3>Test</h3>
            <center><img class="img-responsive" height="180" width="100" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dwjej2tbp/image/upload/v1523002021/KGCAS_SK_eyehy9.jpg"></center>
            <h4 style="color:#FF0000;position:absolute;left:70%;top:30%;" align="center" ><span id="iTimeShow">Time Remaining: </span><br/><span id='timer' style="font-size:25px;"></span></h4>
            <h2>Exercise 1</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="question"></div>
        <ul class="choiceList"></ul>
        <div class="quizMessage"></div>
        <div class="result"></div>
        <button class="preButton">Previous</button>
        <button class="nextButton">Next</button>
    </div>
```

with CSS as follows

```
 h1 {
    font-family:'Gabriola', serif;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    font-family:'Cambria', serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
input[type=radio] {
    border: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2em;
}
p {
    font-family:'Gabriola', serif;
}
/* Quiz Classes */
 .quizContainer {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;*/
    position: relative;
}
.quizcontainer #quiz1
{
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px orange;
font-family:"Georgia", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nextButton {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
   /* width: 150px;*/
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    /*clear: both;*/
    color: red;
    font-family:'Gabriola', serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    float:right;
    right:30%;
}

.preButton {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /*width: 150px;*/
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    /*clear: both;*/
    color: red;
    font-family:'Gabriola', serif;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    float:left;
    left:30%;
}

.question {
    font-family:'Century', serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #f3dc45;
    text-align: center;
}
.quizMessage {
    background-color: peachpuff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:'Gabriola', serif;
    color: red;
    position:absolute;
    top:80%;
    left:40%;
}
.choiceList {
    font-family: 'Arial', serif;
    color: #ed12cd;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.result {
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: linen;
    margin: auto;
    color:green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:'Verdana', serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:80%;
    left:30%;
}
/* End of Quiz Classes */
```

I want to give some pointers before doing the quiz. And this quiz is only done by certain people. Therefore, I think it is better not to immediately display the first question (because when the link is opened, this quiz will immediately display question number one and running time).

I think changes should be made to the code below. I've tried removing displayCurrentQuestion (); , but the quis didn't work. I've also tried to replace it with a button but it doesn't work.

```
    (document).ready(function () 
{
    // Display the first question
    displayCurrentQuestion();
  
    $(this).find(".quizMessage").hide();
    $(this).find(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    timedCount();
    
    $(this).find(".preButton").on("click", function () 
    {       
        
        if (!quizOver) 
        {
            if(currentQuestion == 0) { return false; }
    
            if(currentQuestion == 1) {
              $(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            
                currentQuestion--; // Since we have already displayed the first question on DOM ready
                if (currentQuestion < questions.length) 
                {
                    displayCurrentQuestion();
                    
                }                   
        } else {
            if(viewingAns == 3) { return false; }
            currentQuestion = 0; viewingAns = 3;
            viewResults();      
        }
    });

    
    // On clicking next, display the next question
    $(this).find(".nextButton").on("click", function () 
    {
        if (!quizOver) 
        {
            
            var val = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

            if (val == undefined) 
            {
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").text("Please select an answer");
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").show();
            } 
            else 
            {
                // TODO: Remove any message -> not sure if this is efficient to call this each time....
                $(document).find(".quizMessage").hide();
                if (val == questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer) 
                {
                    correctAnswers++;
                }
                iSelectedAnswer[currentQuestion] = val;
                
                currentQuestion++; // Since we have already displayed the first question on DOM ready
                if(currentQuestion >= 1) {
                      $('.preButton').prop("disabled", false);
                }
                if (currentQuestion < questions.length) 
                {
                    displayCurrentQuestion();
                    
                } 
                else 
                {
                    displayScore();
                    $('#iTimeShow').html('Time is Over!!!!');
                    $('#timer').html("You scored: " + correctAnswers + " out of: " + questions.length);
                    c=115;
                    $(document).find(".preButton").text("View Answer");
                    $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Play Again?");
                    quizOver = true;
                    return false;
                    
                }
            }
                    
        }   
        else 
        { // quiz is over and clicked the next button (which now displays 'Play Again?'
            quizOver = false; $('#iTimeShow').html('Time Remaining:'); iSelectedAnswer = [];
            $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Next");
            $(document).find(".preButton").text("Previous");
             $(".preButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            resetQuiz();
            viewingAns = 1;
            displayCurrentQuestion();
            hideScore();
        }
    });
});
```

How do you make the initial quiz display display the password form and start button? of course if the password is wrong then the question will not appear.

Comment: Can you shorten down your code to where you have an issue please? It makes it easier to answer your question when it is like this. Thank you!

Comment: @sven, I have added parts that may need to be repaired